# scroller is not working(iphone)

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, textfield

I have added a scrollview to my view like following:

```
   _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
            _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
            [_scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
            [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
[container addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

however the scroller shows up on the screen and I can scroll it but the texfields inside it are not working.How can I fix this?

```
- (UIView *)Form
{
    if (!_Form) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, kSignUpViewVisibleHeight, kDeviceWidth, 310.0);
        UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
        [_scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
        [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];



        CGFloat y = 15.0;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, kDeviceWidth - 2*15.0, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
        field.placeholder = @"Email*";
        field.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
        [container addSubview:field];
        self.FormEmail = field;
        self.FormEmail.delegate = self;
        self.FormEmail.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        self.FormEmail.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        CGFloat spacing = 8.0;
        y = frame.origin.y + kDefaultTextFieldHeight + spacing;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, kDeviceWidth - 2*15.0, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
        field.placeholder = @"Password*";
        field.secureTextEntry = YES;
        [container addSubview:field];
        self.FormPassword = field;
        self.FormPassword.delegate = self;
        self.FormPassword.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        self.FormPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        y = frame.origin.y + kDefaultTextFieldHeight + spacing;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, kDeviceWidth - 2*15.0, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
        field.placeholder = @"Confirm Password*";
        field.secureTextEntry = YES;
        [container addSubview:field];
        self.FormConfirmPassword = field;
        self.FormConfirmPassword.delegate = self;
        self.FormConfirmPassword.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
        self.FormConfirmPassword.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        y = frame.origin.y + kDefaultTextFieldHeight + 16.0;
        CGFloat w = (kDeviceWidth - 2 * 15.0) / 2;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, w - 2.0, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
        field.placeholder = @"First Name*";
        [container addSubview:field];
        self.FirstName = field;
        self.FirstName.delegate = self;
        self.FirstName.clearButtonMode =UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        frame = CGRectMake(15.0 + w + 2.0, y, w - 2.0, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
        field.placeholder = @"Last Name*";
        [container addSubview:field];
        self.FormLastName = field;
        self.FormLastName.delegate = self;
        self.FormLastName.clearButtonMode =UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

        y = frame.origin.y + kDefaultTextFieldHeight + spacing;
        frame = CGRectMake(15.0, y, w, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
        field.placeholder = @"Birthday";
        [container addSubview:field];
        self.FormBirthday = field;
        self.FormBirthday.delegate = self;

        frame = CGRectMake(15.0 + w + 5.0, y, w - 5.0, kDefaultTextFieldHeight);
        SegmentControl *gender = [[SegmentControl alloc] initWithFrame:frame items:@[@"Boy", @"Girl"]];
        [container addSubview:gender];
        self.Formtype = gender;

        y = frame.origin.y + kDefaultTextFieldHeight + 20.0;
        frame = CGRectMake((container.frame.size.width - 192.0) / 2, y, 192.0, 33.0);
        UIButton *signUpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        signUpButton.frame = frame;
        [signUpButton setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateButton:signUpButton];
        [container addSubview:signUpButton];

        y = frame.origin.y + kDefaultTextFieldHeight + 8.0;
        frame = CGRectMake((container.frame.size.width - 192.0) / 2, y, 192.0, 34.0);
        UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        cancelButton.frame = frame;
        [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.appDel.styleManager decorateButton:cancelButton];
        [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelRegistration:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [container addSubview:cancelButton];
        [container addSubview:self.scrollView];


        _Form = container;
    }
    return _Form;
}
```

I have added the form that needs to be scrolled.

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates the textfields inside it, including where they add them to the display?

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: You don't add anything to the scroll view - only to the container. All your views are siblings of the scroll view, not subviews of it. So to make it scroll you need to have them be subviews of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scroll view scrolls its subviews only; you should add the various text fields as subviews of `_scrollView` rather than of `container`.